# converting video to images/frames without locally downloading video in python

Tags: image, python-3.x, video-streaming

I am looking for a python code to convert video to frames after every particular duration let's say after every 2 seconds from given URL. Without downloading the video locally. Is it possible?

Comment: Did you get anything for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. I had to download the videos and write my own python script eventually.